# How to change Jupyter notebook html output template?

Tags: python, html, themes, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I use `jupytherthemes` module to change Jupyter notebook theme to solarized. For some reason, I needed to reinstall the Anaconda. After that I was not able to use jupytherthemse and I just used another custom.css file and left it in .jupyter/custom directory.

My notebook theme is fine but when I export it as html, nbconver uses the old theme--solarized. I searched a lot to find a way to reset the template to the default template or to custom.css I am using for notebook. I was not able to find any solution.

any thought would be much appreciated.

here is `full.tpl` content:

```
{%- extends 'basic.tpl' -%}
{% from 'mathjax.tpl' import mathjax %}


{%- block header -%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{%- block html_head -%}
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>{{resources['metadata']['name']}}</title>

{%- if "widgets" in nb.metadata -%}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jupyter-js-widgets@2.0.*/dist/embed.js"></script>
{%- endif-%}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

{% for css in resources.inlining.css -%}
    <style type="text/css">
    {{ css }}
    </style>
{% endfor %}

<style type="text/css">
/* Overrides of notebook CSS for static HTML export */
body {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 8px;
}

div#notebook {
  overflow: visible;
  border-top: none;
}

{%- if resources.global_content_filter.no_prompt-%}
div#notebook-container{
  padding: 6ex 12ex 8ex 12ex;
}
{%- endif -%}

@media print {
  div.cell {
    display: block;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  } 
  div.output_wrapper { 
    display: block;
    page-break-inside: avoid; 
  }
  div.output { 
    display: block;
    page-break-inside: avoid; 
  }
}
</style>

<!-- Custom stylesheet, it must be in the same directory as the html file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">

<!-- Loading mathjax macro -->
{{ mathjax() }}
{%- endblock html_head -%}
</head>
{%- endblock header -%}

{% block body %}
<body>
  <div tabindex="-1" id="notebook" class="border-box-sizing">
    <div class="container" id="notebook-container">
{{ super() }}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
{%- endblock body %}

{% block footer %}
{{ super() }}
</html>
{% endblock footer %}
```

Comment: I don't have a full answer to your question. But I was hunting around for something similar and found: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html in case it's useful.